# lucene 3.0.3 | QueryParser

Tags: lucene.net, lucene

I have created my own custom analyzer made them search for **c#**, **.net**, **c++** etc.

While I am trying to search **c#**, **.net**, **c++**  **QueryParser** parse **.net** to **.net** and **C++** to **C++**. So it works fine. But in case of **C#** QueryParser parse it to **C** which makes trouble for me.

Also tried to use **MultiFieldQueryParser** but it also do the same.

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated!!!

Comment: Please post some code showing which filters/tokenizers/analyzers you are using to compose your custom analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

What is operation implemented by your custom analyzer?
Is your analyzer connected to query parsing process?
Are you using [AnalyzingQueryParser](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/queryParser/analyzing/AnalyzingQueryParser.html) that would enable you hooking up analyzer to query parsing?

Comment: yes, analyzer i have created takes part while creating QueryParser object. no, i am not using AnalyzingQueryParser.                                                     I have got a solution while searching (c#.) it parse to c# , mean i have to put a dot(.) after c# which make every thing working fine. but, still finding real solution!!!

Comment: Substitute QueryParser with AnalyzingQueryParser, this will enable you to pass your analyzer when parsing query. Currently, extra dot is removed by word based tokenizer.